# Jquery validation not working as supposed

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days now without success, tried all tutorials on it and going through pieces of codes that actually work, but without any avail.

Most likely it will be something rather easy to find, but my jquery knowledge is very limited.

The problem is that i can not get the validation to work properly, earlier on it worked only for one field (Email field) with using the "Class = required email" attribute. However also that one stopped working.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#forumulier").validate({
    rules: {
            telephone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                        },

            name: {
                required: true,
                    },

            surname: {
                required: true,
                    },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                }
            },
    messages: {
            telephone: {
                digits: "* voer een geldig telefoon nummer in"
                },
            name: {
                required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
                },
            surname: {
                required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
                },
            email: { 
                required: "* voer een geldig email adres in"
                }
            }
        submitHandler: function(form){
            return false;
            }
});
})
```

### ------

```
<form id="formulier" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <div class="group">
            <label for="name" class="label">Naam*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            </div>

            <div class="group">
            <label for="surname" class="label">Achternaam*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname"/>
            </div>

            <div class="group">
            <label for="email" class="label">Email*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
            </div>

            <div class="group">
            <label for="telephone" class="label">Telefoon*:</label>
            <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" />
            </div>

            <label for="extra" class="label">Opmerkingen:</label>
            <textarea class="small-area"></textarea>


            <div class="clear"></div>

            <button type="submit" class="send">Verzenden</button>
        </form>
```

Thanks for any

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon at the very end?

Comment: That wouldn't break it though...

Comment: Are you using this plugin? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Yes im using that plugin, thing with the comma's is that i just tried that version (I assume has the commas in the right place) but nothing changed.. form is there, but I can still get through with an email address without "@"  and a phone number consisting out of letters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting the messages for the validation you need to set a message for each validation you are using: required, date, email, etc.

like this.

```
messages: {
    telephone: {
        required: " your message here",
        digits: "* voer een geldig telefoon nummer in"

    },
    name: {
        required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
    },
    surname: {
        required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
    },
    email: { 
        required: "* voer een geldig email adres in",
        email: " your message here"
    }
},
submitHandler: function(form){
   form.submit();
}
```

This should work for your example.

Update..
this is a full example.
i've used your code + mine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<div class="group">
<label for="name" class="label">Naam*:</label>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
</div>

<div class="group">
<label for="surname" class="label">Achternaam*:</label>
<input type="text" name="surname"/>
</div>

div class="group">
<label for="email" class="label">Email*:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" />
</div>

<div class="group">
<label for="telephone" class="label">Telefoon*:</label>
<input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" />
</div>

<label for="extra" class="label">Opmerkingen:</label>
<textarea class="small-area"></textarea>


<div class="clear"></div>

<input type="submit" class="send">
</form>​
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").validate({
rules: {
telephone: {
required: true,
digits: true,
},
name: {
required: true,
},
surname: {
required: true,
},
email: {
required: true,
email: true,
}
},
messages: {
telephone: {
required: " your message here",
digits: "* voer een geldig telefoon nummer in"
},
name: {
required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
},
surname: {
required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
},
email: { 
required: "* voer een geldig email adres in",
email: " your message here"
}
},
submitHandler: function(form){
form.submit();
}
});
});          
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</body>
</html>
```

check out your submit button. you got button type='submit'. when i use it, it didn't work. change it to input type='submit'

Comment: Thanks for the input. But, still not working, no change, no message is displayed, nothing happens upon submitting the form.

Comment: Okay that did the trick. It was all about the submit button! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#forumulier").validate({
    rules: {
            telephone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
                        },

            name: {
                required: true
                    },

            surname: {
                required: true
                    },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
                }
            },
    messages: {
            telephone: {
                digits: "* voer een geldig telefoon nummer in"
                },
            name: {
                required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
                },
            surname: {
                required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
                },
            email: { 
                required: "* voer een geldig email adres in"
                }
            },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            form.submit();
            }
});
});
```

Looks like you just have too many commas. You need to put your code through a javascript debugger which will let you know when you have simple syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for that, I played around quite a lot with the commas and brackets, unfortunately with this code it is still not working.

Comment: Not sure exactly how that plugin works but you may need to add id's to all your inputs. The telephone input looks correct but the rest do not have any id attribute.

Comment: According to the documentation they need the name attribute, just double checked it by adding id's to it, no change.

Comment: what happens when you run it through firefox firebug javascript debugger or the internet explorer debugger (hit f12 and select script, then click start debugging)

Comment: I tried it on the Safari debugger which shows no errors. (example can be found: http://financieeladviesvooriedereen.nl/fb/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the problems pointed out by others with the commas, you've simply misspelled `formulier` in your call to validate, so it is not attaching the validation code to anything (you used "for**u**mulier").

So fix it to this:

```
$("#formulier").validate({
    rules: {
        telephone: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
                    },

        name: {
            required: true
                },

        surname: {
            required: true
                },

        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
            }
        },
    messages: {
        telephone: {
            digits: "* voer een geldig telefoon nummer in"
            },
        name: {
            required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
            },
        surname: {
            required: "* dit veld is verplicht"
            },
        email: { 
            required: "* voer een geldig email adres in"
            }
        },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        return false;
        }
});​​​​
```

Commas removed for the last item in each object.  Comma added before the submitHandler.  `forumulier` changed to `formulier`.

Looks like this now:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Xn5YJ/

Comment: The miss-spelled id for form is just in the solution contributed by Ricbermo. Indeed commas etc were all over the place, when i changed my code manually toward the solution the only thing that caused it to work was the change from <button type="submit"> to <input type="submit">. Takes for the input!

Comment: ... and yet, my copy of your code works perfectly with a `button`.